# Why does the healthcare sector need its own DICOM standard instead of using XML or JSON?

Tags: computers

I wonder why the healthcare sector needs its own DICOM standard instead of using XML or JSON.
I mean, they could simply use well-established formats and just define their own field-value pairs instead, which would significantly decrease the amount of work needed.
What are the main reasons for this? Is this a historical leftover that never got ported to modern formats, or are there practical reasons, e.g. performance and file sizes?
Or is this because for medical devices, they are responsible for any libraries that are included, anyway, and thus it does not really make a difference anymore whether you build it from scratch or reuse code that already exists?

(Tag used because non of the existing tags seems to fit)

[DICOM in the XML Schema Design Language (XSDL)](http://www.newportinstruments.com/cytometryml/pdf/DICOM_XSDL_APIII_09.pdf)

[XML-Based DICOM Data Format](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3043771/)

**Edit:** I just realized that HL7 v3 already uses XML, thus I changed the question's title.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124937/discussion-on-question-by-kaiya-why-does-the-healthcare-sector-need-its-own-dico).

Comment: Historic reasons and backwards compatibility I would have to guess.

Answer (score 4):

I would flip this question on its head and ask what you think the benefit would be to changing the underlying file format?  There are a few points that I can think of that might help frame the context for you, but there is probably no "correct answer" in the SE-sense.

Imagine if a new file format were to be developed in medical imaging which stored its data in JSON.  There would still need to be a separate documented standard that exhaustively details how imaging data is coded in this new format.  That already exists in the form of the DICOM standard, so why rewrite it when it will still need to be interpreted by any library using this new format?

Secondly, remember that in clincial practice medical software is a diverse mix of vendors from all over the world, some large, some small.  There is no unifying body that mandates how software companies design their products, and interoperability is already extremely challenging.  Given the established nature of DICOM, there is little incentive for these vendors to invest money in creating / utilising a different standard.  Even if they were to do so, hospitals are notorious for being stuck on legacy software.  [This article](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2010/jan/22/internet-explorer-nhs-vulnerability) from 2010 gives you an idea of the state of play.  Even today, one of the pieces of software I use on a daily basis only works in Internet Explorer, not in Edge/Chrome.

It is probably worth noting that DICOM is not the only medical imaging file format in use, although it is probably the most prevalent in the clincial setting.  For example, the [NifTI format](https://nifti.nimh.nih.gov/) is widely used in the neuroimaging research space.

Bear in mind, as well, that medical imaging data is very heterogeneous and so writing a new standard is not a small task.  For example:

- A chest X-ray is a 2D grayscale image
- A CT scan is multiple stacked 2D images, sometimes with several series (i.e. several associated stacks) in a single scan
- A PETCT scan would include a co-registered map onto a CT displaying tracer avidity detected by the gamma camera
- A 4DCT would also incorporate a time element into this
- DICOM-RT objects could include information such as radiotherapy dose planned to a particular voxel, or the physical position of a radiotherapy field

This is before you get into the metadata associated with it, which ranges from patient demographics, the field strength of the MRI scanner, the frame of reference of the scan and beyond.

Finally, what do you mean when you say

> it would significantly decrease the amount of work needed"?

There exist already many libraries (e.g. [pydicom](https://pydicom.github.io/)) to work with DICOM, if there were a JSON-based format they would then need to be developed for that.

Comment: There is also https://xkcd.com/927/ and that a lot of medical equipment using DICOM is decades old and made by numerous different manufacturers. It's not like you could issue a Windows Update and convert everything to another format tomorrow. OP also seems to be missing that DICOM is more than just a storage format (this answer touches on that with references to metadata) so it makes no sense to imagine "JSON" as in any way equivalent.

Comment: @BryanKrause OP is very much aware of that DICOM is more than a file format. OP is also very much aware of the security impact that DICOM has.

Comment: The observation that underlies my question is, that DICOM does not really more then allowing to share an image and add some metadata to it. That is no medical-specific problem, that can be solved with any non-medical file formats and transmission protocols. Sure, you want interoperability, but that again is not medical-specific. We want that interoperability all over the internet, and somehow, engineers manage to add security updates and slowly deprecate insecure functions. I don't get why this parallel development is necessary at all, especially because it does not seem to scale very well.

Comment: Also, there exist even more libraries that work with JSON and XML. The only work I see that would need to be done is defining the meta-data fields and how to handle them (most part of this is c/p work...). I am not at all talking about inventing a new file format, I am talking about using formats and protocols that are well-established.

Comment: @kaiya It seems more like you want to complain about this than listen to answers to your question. My comment was that "replace DICOM with JSON" makes absolutely no sense. "Make a new standard that incorporates aspects of DICOM and stores in a JSON-compatible format" might, but then you have the issue noted by that XKCD.

Comment: @bryan I am listening, it is just, that I cannot follow your argumentation to put it like this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the 'History' link on the DICOM web site:

> - https://www.dicomstandard.org/history

in 2013, [DICOMweb](https://www.dicomstandard.org/dicomweb/) was introduced, and this uses [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web services, which uses HTML, XML and JSON.

> Second generation RESTful web services defined to retrieve, store and query DICOM images. The suite of web services is re-branded as DICOMweb™, and is aligned with the upcoming HL7 FHIR web services:

Comment: Not sure I see how this answers the question. I think you need more explanation.

Comment: @CareyGregory; I've answered the question from the title - DICOMweb **does** use XML and JSON.

Comment: Yes, is uses semi-modern web technologies including XML and JSON, but they also still transfer DICOM objects, so they did not discard the DICOM file format, which is why it does not really the question. I am rather interested why they hold onto it.